Configuring a new router without disconnecting current one
I have a router at home with 2 different networks. One for my family, and one for guests. I am trying to replace my old router with a new one without disconnecting the old one. That way internet never goes down. Here's what I have tried to do in order to configure my new router:
new router: EdgeRouter ER-8
Connect it to my computer which is running ethernet from a switch, and connect it to the switch ethernet as well.
I go to command line and type: ipconfig, and see a standard 192.168.1.1 gateway.
I type it onto the web and it shows my old router that is in use. I'm not sure what I'm suppose to do. AN=ny help would work.
I'm running windows 11. My new router is pinging just fine when i disconnect wifi and command: ping 192.168.1.1 -t, but nothing seems to help. The goal is to enter the web and add the default username and password for my new router that the seller gave me, but again, im being redirected to the old router.
Maybe I need to connect directly to the modem? Again, I CANNOT DISCONNECT THE OLD ROUTER. I will do that at night when the new one is ready to go. Extra points if i can have them both on DHCP and switch them out without disconnecting devices.

so I'm understanding that you already have a host on 192.168.1.1. so what port on the router are you connecting to the switch? per the quick start guide, port eth0 is configured to use dhcp client, so it will request an IP address from your current router. you should be able to look on the current router to see what IP it was given. then you can point your webbrowser to that IP to enter the ER-8 management pages so you can set the router up.  https://dl.ubnt.com/guides/edgemax/EdgeRouter_ER-8_QSG.pdf

another note, as long as all your clients are configured to use DHCP, I'd strongly recommend setting the new router up to use a different network, like 192.168.5.0/24 or whatever. you can use a different network port to configure the router than you use set up for use once you are ready to swap them out (so perhaps use 192.168.7.0 for eth1 and leave eth0 as DHCP, so you can continue to use your existing network while you are configuring it.

just checked in with our tech guy. He said the device was broken or outdated. Gonna get a new device. Not sure if an er8 can be outdated but oh well

yeah, an ER-8 is not at all obsolete. I'd get specifics from him. the device may be broken. its also possible that the tech is unfamiliar with the differences between devices that support the ubiquity "UnifiOS" platform vs the "EdgeOS" platform.  If they expect to manage the device using a cloud-key or unifiOS install (bare-metal or VM), then that won't work. Now it sounds like your intial question was about a home network, but now its sounding "enterprisy". which is it?
